# Trying to avoid polymorphic association in a schema for dynamic fields

Tags: sql, polymorphic-associations

I want to create a dynamic fields system. The idea is that the owner will be able to create dynamic fields for let's say, the customers of his company. The problem is that with the database structure that I came up with, requires the use of polymorphic association. 
My structure is the following:

1. The fields table that consists of the following columns:

   **ID, FieldName, FieldType** (The field type can be avoided, probably)
2. The field value tables (There are multiple value tables, one for every data type of the dynamic fields ex. A table to store the values that are DATETIMES, a table that stores the values that are DECIMALS and so on.).These tables have identical structure but with a different data type for their value column! They consist of the following columns:

   **ID, FieldID, CustomerID, FieldValue**

Now, in order to get the field value I have to do a bunch of **LEFT JOINs** between the **Value Tables** and the **Fields Table** and keep only the value column that its value is not **NULL**, since that only one value column if any will have a value! Of course this isn't efficient at all and I am trying to avoid it. Any suggestions even if they require a completely different database structure at all are welcome. I am also using MySQL along with EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: There have been endless discussions of this horrendous 'ultimate flexibility' model, called EAV - Entity Attribute Value. Search for that term here and you will find them. 
My 2 cents - save yourself the trouble and don't go there. Many have tried, most have failed miserable and still lick their wounds. 
Relational databases are meant to model reality, not abstract representations thereof. 
By the way, there are no fields in a SQL - there are rows and columns. search that too...

Comment: I have already read about EAV but it didn't really help. And I believe that there is a miss consumption here. I never said that there are field in SQL . The FieldValue, FieldName etc are the name of the columns of the DB schema I am planning to use...